# ICustomMarshaler::MarshalNativeToManaged, receiving correct data from native dll “looses” the object it returns

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using my own marshaler that implements ICustomMarshaler to work with native(unmanaged) dll C function.

In the function MarshalNativeToManaged I do see the correct results coming from the dll side. The problem is that the object that MarshalNativeToManaged returns is not "used". The object in the calling function with (In, Out) param is not changed.

(It looks like it is exactly the same problem that was previosly discussed here "C#: Object with custom marshaller not containing data after PInvoke call")
[C#: Object with custom marshaller not containing data after PInvoke call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2636166/1415939)

The simple class:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    class CMA { 
        public int a; 
        char b;
        public char get_b() { return b; }
    }
```

The signature of the function looks like this:

```
[DllImport("first.dll", EntryPoint = "hack")]
    public static extern int hack([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler,
                                            MarshalTypeRef=typeof(ZMarshal))] CMA cma);
```

somewhere in the main I call it like this:

```
int retcode = hack(cma);
```

In the MarshalNativeToManaged I do see correct result from the dll function call.

```
    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        // everything is fine with pNativeData;
        // but let us even say I ignore it
        // and return the object in the following way:
        CMA cma = new CMA();
        cma.a = 999;
        return cma; // this will be lost. I mean cma object in the main will not be changed
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Just a quick note: I do want to know how to handle it using CustomMarshaler not "some other way around" :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok it looks like I know what is going on now.

The trick is that while dealing with Object we are dealing with pointers really (no matter how hard C# tries to hide that fact) and step by step:
1)  hack(CMA* pCMA);
2)  MarshalManagedToNative(void* pCMA) // C# passes the pointer we passed to hack here
3)  Void* MarshalNativeToManaged(void *_some_PTR_to_memory_visible_to_managed_and_unmanaged_area)
And here is the QUESTION what does .NET do with this Void* ptr that this function returns? If one does not use ref it has no way to change the object in the hack(cma). This pointer is simply not used anywhere. The function could have been void.

```
    public class ZMarshal : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ICustomMarshaler
{
    static ZMarshal static_instance;
    object oo;
    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object o)
    {
        if (!(o is CMA))
           throw new System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException("Blabala");
        oo = o;
```

And later on in the MarshalNativeToManaged

```
    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {

        // some code that deals with the pNativeData really
        // but for our example only let us say we simply ignore what we just got
        // from the unmanaged world and simply change our object

        ((CMA)oo).a = 999;
        return oo; // this will not be lost now :)
```

If we would use ref like this hack(ref CMA);  // thanks to the previous answer BTW
In this case it is hack(CMA**pp) and .NET does use the pointer we return from MarshalNativeToManaged *pp = oo;

The bottom line is we either have to keep our pointer and change the value of memory it points to, or (using ref) pass a pointer to pointer (yes old good ** really) and change  the value of the pointer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The C# language requires that you declare an argument as *ref* or *out* to allow it to return a new value.  Fix:

```
[DllImport("first.dll", EntryPoint = "hack")]
public static extern int hack(
    [In, Out]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef=typeof(ZMarshal))]
    ref CMA cma);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is one of the ways to handle it. I think I know what is going on here and I answered my own question already. When (and if) you have some time please have a look and add some comments/corrections.

Comment: Hmm, no, a global variable is *not* the way to handle it.

Comment: It is not a global one, it is a member variable of the class ZMarshal. BTW how do we control which instance of the marshaler class itself we use?

Comment: I have tried `[In, Out] ref` in the similar situation, and ended up by getting invalid pointer from native code. Approach with field at least works.